# how to integrate "Search Nominatim control " library and openlayers "measure" example for geocoding and measure area simultaneous

Tags: javascript, openlayers, nominatim

I have a code from the openlayers library and example for measuring the length and area on the map.I also have a code from the Nominatim library for "Search Nominatim control" and Geocoding on the map.I put these code together.Each code works fine, but it does not work when it comes together.The bug is here, after two clicks, no longer a point to measure the length or area is selected.Please advise which section to correct or change.
Is there a simpler way to do this?
Thanks

**first code for geocoding:**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------
    
        Copyright (c) 2017-2018 Jean-Marc VIGLINO,
        released under CeCILL-B (french BSD like) licence: http://www.cecill.info/
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------>
        <title>ol-ext: Search Nominatim control</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    
        <meta name="description" content="Control to add a grid reference to a map." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="ol3, control, search, BAN, french, places, autocomplete" />
    
        <!-- FontAwesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE 9 bug on ajax tranport  -->
        <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.3/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js'></script>
        <![endif]-->
    
        <!-- Openlayers -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,Object.assign"></script>
        
        <!-- ol-ext -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"/>
        <style>
            .ol-search ul {
                color: #333;
                font-size:0.85em;
                max-width: 21em;
            }
            .ol-search ul i {
                display: block;
                color: #333;
                font-size:0.85em;
            }
            .info {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .info a img {
                height: 100px;
                margin-right: .5em;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        
    
        <!-- DIV pour la carte -->
        <div id="map" style="width:50%; height:50%;"></div>
    
        <div class="options">
            <label>
                <input id="polygon" type="checkbox" onclick="search.set('polygon', $(this).prop('checked')); search.search();" /> 
                extract polygons<br/>(may slow down requests)
            </label>
            <br/>
            <i>Use the search control to start a new search.</i>
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Layers
        var layers = [ new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }) ];
    
        // The map
        var map = new ol.Map
            ({  target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View
                ({  zoom: 5,
                    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.39, 35.70])
                }),
                interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate:false, pinchRotate:false }),
                layers: layers
            });
    
        // Current selection
        var sLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector(),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 5,
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
                        color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                        width: 3
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
                    })
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
                    color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                    width: 3
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
                })
            })
        });
        map.addLayer(sLayer);
    
        // Set the search control 
        var search = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
            {   //target: $(".options").get(0),
                polygon: $("#polygon").prop("checked"),
                position: true  // Search, with priority to geo position
            });
        map.addControl (search);
    
        // Select feature when click on the reference index
        search.on('select', function(e)
            {   // console.log(e);
                sLayer.getSource().clear();
                // Check if we get a geojson to describe the search
                if (e.search.geojson) {
                    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                    var f = format.readFeature(e.search.geojson, { dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() });
                    sLayer.getSource().addFeature(f);
                    var view = map.getView();
                    var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(f.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
                    var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
                    var center = ol.extent.getCenter(f.getGeometry().getExtent());
                    // redraw before zoom
                    setTimeout(function(){
                            view.animate({
                            center: center,
                            zoom: Math.min (zoom, 16)
                        });
                    }, 100);
                }
                else {
                    map.getView().animate({
                        center:e.coordinate,
                        zoom: Math.max (map.getView().getZoom(),16)
                    });
                }
            });
    
        </script>
        
    </body>
    </html>

**second code for measure area:**

  see openlayers example "measure"

**Both the code together:**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Measure</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
        <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
        <!---------------------------------------
        -----------------------------------------
        -----------------------------------------
        -->
        <!-- FontAwesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE 9 bug on ajax tranport  -->
        <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.3/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js'></script>
        <![endif]-->
    
        <!-- Openlayers -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,Object.assign"></script>
        
        <!-- ol-ext -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"/>  -->
        <style>
                .ol-search ul {
                color: #333;
                font-size:0.85em;
                max-width: 21em;
            }
            .ol-search ul i {
                display: block;
                color: #333;
                font-size:0.85em;
            }
            .info {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .info a img {
                height: 100px;
                margin-right: .5em;
                float: left;
            }
            </style>  
            <!------------------------------
            --------------------------------
            -------------------------------->
        <style>
          .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: white;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
            white-space: nowrap;
          }
          .tooltip-measure {
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: bold;
          }
          .tooltip-static {
            background-color: #ffcc33;
            color: black;
            border: 1px solid white;
          }
          .tooltip-measure:before,
          .tooltip-static:before {
            border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-right: 6px solid transparent;
            border-left: 6px solid transparent;
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -6px;
            margin-left: -7px;
            left: 50%;
          }
          .tooltip-static:before {
            border-top-color: #ffcc33;
          }  
          .map {
            height: 50%;
            width: 70%;
          }   
    
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <label>Measure: &nbsp;</label>
          <select id="type">
            <option value="length">Length (LineString)</option>
            <option value="area">Area (Polygon)</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <script>
          var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          });
    
          var source = new ol.source.Vector();
    
          var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#ffcc33',
                width: 2
              }),
              image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: '#ffcc33'
                })
              })
            })
          });
    
    
          /**
           * Currently drawn feature.
           * @type {ol.Feature}
           */
          var sketch;
    
    
          /**
           * The help tooltip element.
           * @type {Element}
           */
          var helpTooltipElement;
    
    
          /**
           * Overlay to show the help messages.
           * @type {ol.Overlay}
           */
          var helpTooltip;
    
    
          /**
           * The measure tooltip element.
           * @type {Element}
           */
          var measureTooltipElement;
    
    
          /**
           * Overlay to show the measurement.
           * @type {ol.Overlay}
           */
          var measureTooltip;
    
    
          /**
           * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
           * @type {string}
           */
          var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';
    
    
          /**
           * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
           * @type {string}
           */
          var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';
    
    
          /**
           * Handle pointer move.
           * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} evt The event.
           */
          var pointerMoveHandler = function(evt) {
            if (evt.dragging) {
              return;
            }
            /** @type {string} */
            var helpMsg = 'برای اندازه گیری کلیک کنید';
    
            if (sketch) {
              var geom = (sketch.getGeometry());
              if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
              } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
              }
            }
    
            helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
            helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    
            helpTooltipElement.classList.remove('hidden');
          };
    
    
          var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, vector],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
              center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.39, 35.70]),
              zoom: 15
            }),
            interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate:false, pinchRotate:false })
          });
    
          map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);
    
          map.getViewport().addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            helpTooltipElement.classList.add('hidden');
          });
    
          var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
    
          var draw; // global so we can remove it later
    
    
          /**
           * Format length output.
           * @param {ol.geom.LineString} line The line.
           * @return {string} The formatted length.
           */
          var formatLength = function(line) {
            var length = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);
            var output;
            if (length > 100) {
              output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
                  ' ' + 'km';
            } else {
              output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
                  ' ' + 'm';
            }
            return output;
          };
    
    
          /**
           * Format area output.
           * @param {ol.geom.Polygon} polygon The polygon.
           * @return {string} Formatted area.
           */
          var formatArea = function(polygon) {
            var area = ol.Sphere.getArea(polygon);
            var output;
            if (area > 10000) {
              output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
                  ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
            } else {
              output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
                  ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
            }
            return output;
          };
    
          function addInteraction() {
            var type = (typeSelect.value == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
              source: source,
              type: type,
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                  lineDash: [10, 10],
                  width: 2
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                  radius: 5,
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
                  }),
                  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                  })
                })
              })
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
    
            createMeasureTooltip();
            createHelpTooltip();
    
            var listener;
            draw.on('drawstart',
                function(evt) {
                  // set sketch
                  sketch = evt.feature;
    
                  /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
                  var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
    
                  listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
                    var geom = evt.target;
                    var output;
                    if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                      output = formatArea(geom);
                      tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
                    } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                      output = formatLength(geom);
                      tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
                    }
                    measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
                    measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
                  });
                }, this);
    
            draw.on('drawend',
                function() {
                  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
                  measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
                  // unset sketch
                  sketch = null;
                  // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
                  measureTooltipElement = null;
                  createMeasureTooltip();
                  ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
                }, this);
          }
    
    
          /**
           * Creates a new help tooltip
           */
          function createHelpTooltip() {
            if (helpTooltipElement) {
              helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
            }
            helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
            helpTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip hidden';
            helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
              element: helpTooltipElement,
              offset: [15, 0],
              positioning: 'center-left'
            });
            map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
          }
    
    
          /**
           * Creates a new measure tooltip
           */
          function createMeasureTooltip() {
            if (measureTooltipElement) {
              measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
            }
            measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
            measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
            measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
              element: measureTooltipElement,
              offset: [0, -15],
              positioning: 'bottom-center'
            });
            map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
          }
    
    
          /**
           * Let user change the geometry type.
           */
          typeSelect.onchange = function() {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            addInteraction();
          };
    
          addInteraction();
          
          // Current selection
        var sLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector(),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 5,
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
                        color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                        width: 3
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
                    })
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
                    color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                    width: 3
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
                })
            })
        });
        map.addLayer(sLayer);
    
        // Set the search control 
        var search = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
            {   //target: $(".options").get(0),
                polygon: $("#polygon").prop("checked"),
                position: true  // Search, with priority to geo position
            });
        map.addControl (search);
    
        // Select feature when click on the reference index
        search.on('select', function(e)
            {   // console.log(e);
                sLayer.getSource().clear();
                // Check if we get a geojson to describe the search
                if (e.search.geojson) {
                    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                    var f = format.readFeature(e.search.geojson, { dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() });
                    sLayer.getSource().addFeature(f);
                    var view = map.getView();
                    var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(f.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
                    var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
                    var center1 = ol.extent.getCenter(f.getGeometry().getExtent());
                    // redraw before zoom
                    setTimeout(function(){
                            view.animate({
                            center: center1,
                            zoom: Math.min (zoom, 16)
                        });
                    }, 100);
                }
                else {
                    map.getView().animate({
                        center:e.coordinate,
                        zoom: Math.max (map.getView().getZoom(),16)
                    });
                }
            });
    
        </script>
        <div class="options">
            <label>
                <input id="polygon" type="checkbox" onclick="search.set('polygon', $(this).prop('checked')); search.search();" /> 
                extract polygons<br/>(may slow down requests)
            </label>
            <br/>
            <i>Use the search control to start a new search.</i>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are including both https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js (and both of the corresponding css links).  Use only one version.  Openlayer 4 uses `ol.Sphere` while in OpenLayers 5 it's `ol.sphere`  Because you linked OpenLayers 5 after OpenLayers 4 the code is using OpenLayers 5 and expects `ol.sphere`

Comment: Thank you so much. You really helped me. The problem was solved.